# Arc connectedness and connectedness of $X = \{(x,y) \mid y= 0 \} \cup \{(x,y)\mid x>0, y = \frac{1}{x} \}$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> Let  $X = \{(x,y) \mid y= 0 \} \cup \{(x,y)| x>0, y = \frac{1}{x} \}$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is it arc-connected? Is it connected?

I first decided to study the connectedness of $X$. My approach was this: if $X$ is connected, then it cannot be expressed as the union of two open disjoint sets.

So let's put $A_1 =\{(x,y) \mid y= 0 \}  $ and $A_2 =\{(x,y)\mid x>0, y = \frac{1}{x} \}$. As $X = A_1 \cup A_2$ then in order for it to be connected, $A_1 \subset A_2$ or $A_2 \subset A_1$. So let $(x,y) \in A_1 \cap A_2$, then $x>0, y=0$ and $y = \frac{1}{y}$, which is impossible. Thus $A_1 \cap A_2 = \emptyset$ and thus $X$ isn't connected.

In order to study its arc connectedness, I get into one issue. Let $(x,y)$ and $(x',y') \in X$, then if I put $f(t) = (1-t)(x,y) + t(x',y')$ I easily get $f(0)=(x,y)$ and $f(1)=(x',y')$ the only issues is that $\forall t \in (0,1), f(t) \not \in X$, but it's not enough to disprove the arc-connectedness, as there might still exist a function that would work. So any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: You proved that $X$ is disconnected, this implies dis-arcwise connected...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $A_1=\{(x,y) \mid y<\frac{1}{2\max(x,1)} \}$ and $A_2 =\{(x,y)\mid y > \frac{1}{2\max(x,1)} \}.$ Both sets are open in $\mathbb{R}^2,$ they are disjoint, and $X\subset A_1\cup A_2.$ Thus, $X$ is not connected, and therefore not arc-connected either.

If you want to prove arc-disconnectedness directly, you can assume you have an arc $f:[0,1]\to X$ with $f(0)=(1,0)$ and $f(1)=(1,1),$ and use the intermediate value theorem to show that $f$ must intersect $\{(x,y) \mid y=\frac{1}{2\max(x,1)} \}.$

Comment: I know that connectedness implies arc-connectedness, but is it the other way around? You seem to use that, but I have never seen this property.

Comment: @JohnMayne: You've got it wrong: arc-connectedness implies connectedness. The opposite is not true.